# How to download any file types(dgn,docx etc) using blob in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

Am returning byte Array from API.
My requirement is to download all file types .Getting error(Failed to load PDF document) while downloading dgn files or other types

Am able to convert byte array to blob and downloading PDF files .

```
 download(): void {
        this._service.download().subscribe(data => {
            this.downloadFile(this.byteToBlob(data, 'application/octet-stream', 512));
        },
            error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
            () => console.log('Completed file download.'));
    }


    downloadFile(data: any): void {
        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url);
    }
```

Getting error "Failed to load PDF document " while downloading non PDF files

Answer (score -1):

Hope your backend should like as follows

```
let file = fs.readFileSync(tmpFilePath)
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=temp_file.jpg;status=OK`)
res.send(file)
```

**Angular Service**

```
downloadMedia(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(`/api/event/medias/download/image`, {responseType: 'blob' as 'json'})
```

}

**Component**

```
this.service.downloadMedia().subscribe(result => {
    let imageFormat = result.type.toString()
    saveAs(result, 'temp_file.jpg');
  }
```